# How to fix resharper from deleting editable literal in code snippet when pressing <Enter>?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, resharper, code-snippets

I'm using:

- **Windows 10**
- **Visual Studio 2015** (14.0.25431.1.)
- **Resharper** (10.0.2)

The problem is when I type code snippet shortcut and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> the snippet expands. There are some editable literals in resulting code which initially are set to defaults. I'm satisfied with default values for literals so then I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to exit snippet editing context. The cursor jumps to **$end$** position but at the same time it **erases** the default value for the first editable literal.

I've reinstalled my OS recently and encountered this issue. It worked before with VS2015 and some other Resharper version (probably #9). When I disable Resharper it works fine.

---

Reproduction steps:

Say I want to use simple `for` snippet for c++

1. Write `for` shortcut in method body

[image]

2. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd> in order to invoke code snippet

[image]

3. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in order to confirm suggested defaults

[image]

Notice `size_t` default value that was **selected** on step #2 disappears.